# What could be a good translation for go-getter?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, significado

Last week I received an email from somebody in my organization reminding employees to be aware of having a goo work-life balance while we keep working from home due to the [pandemic](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3320/5481). The email said something in the lines of

> I know that we are a group of **go-getters** and a group of very smart and hardworking people but [it's important to have a good work-life balance: here are some tips].

As usual, when I see some of this terms that don't translate straightforwardly into Spanish I think to myself "this could be an interesting question for Spanish.se".

A "go-getter" is defined as:

> an aggressively enterprising person <sub>[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-getter)</sub>

> someone who is very energetic, determined to be successful, and able to deal with new or difficult situations easily: *"We only recruit go-getters who will be actively involved in the company's development."* <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/go-getter)</sub>

> The definition of a go getter is a person who is ambitious and who isn't afraid to ask for and pursue what he wants. An example of a go getter is a person who has no hesitation about asking her boss for the raise she feels she deserves.

> (idiomatic) One who is motivated or inclined to excel; one who strives to achieve success or improvement: *"He's a promising young go-getter, but he needs to learn some things about office politics.
> Tom Pitella is a go-getter and does not rely on others to prove things in the field of mathematics to him."* <sub>English Wicktionary</sub>

This behavior could easily de *described* in Spanish like "alguien que consigue", "alguien ambicioso", "alguien motivado" but all these proposals may not encompass all the connotations "go-getter" has. A go getter is no just someone ambitious, or motivated or hardworking. It's all those things at once.

So it's easy to understand in English that a "go-getter" is someone who is ambitious and motivated and thus works hard and "goes and gets" what they want. What could be used in Spanish to convey that someone is, among other things, *ambicioso* and *motivado* and *trabaja duro* to *conseguir* his or her goals? A "*conseguidor*" (just joking).

Answer (score 7):

I'd use something like: "(alguien) dispuesto a ir por todo", or "(alguien) que va por todo".

[Here](https://www.songstraducidas.com/letratraducida-Woman_595573.htm) is the translation of a lyric that uses that phrase:

> That woman, she's a boss lady /
> **She's a go getter**, there's no rules baby /
> That woman is a winner /
> That woman is a winner, yeah

> Esa mujer, ella es la jefa /
> **ella va por todo**, no hay reglas nene /
> esa mujer es una ganadora /
> esa mujer es una ganadora, sí

Another option could be: *Somos personas que conseguimos lo que nos proponemos* ([Title of a book](https://play.google.com/store/audiobooks/details/Peter_B_Kyne_Consigue_lo_que_te_propones_Go_Getter?id=AQAAAEBsPHR8CM)), *Somos personas que no nos dejamos amedrentar/aceptamos los desafíos*.

An adjective we'd definitely use where I live is "arremetedor", which has none of the negative connotations some dictionary provide related to violence or aggressiveness, and clearly suggests to me the idea of somebody corageously facing any difficulties that might arise.

Answer (score 4):

Inicialmente pensé en que *[decidido](https://dle.rae.es/decidido)* podría servir, pero creo que se queda lejos de lo que es un *go-getter*:

> Resuelto, audaz, que actúa con decisión

Así que voy a responder con un anglicismo. Creo que una palabra que podría servir como equivalente en español podría ser:

> ***[crack](https://dle.rae.es/crack)***
>
> Voz ingl.
>
> 2. m. Deportista de extraordinaria calidad.

Aunque en principio la voz se usó para los deportistas, hoy día se puede usar en cualquier ámbito para denotar a alguien muy bueno en lo que hace, como demuestra el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Quince canciones de rock en español con influencias argentinas —su padre nació allí— que su abuela, Asunción Balaguer, escucha encantada en los conciertos: "Ella sí que es un crack, se queda loca cuando va a verme, disfruta mucho, sobre todo porque ella sabe de música, lo mismo toca el piano que se arranca a cantar ópera".*
>
> La Razón Digital, 01/04/2003 : Luis Rodrigo: "Mi abuelo no fue nunca de dar consejos" (España).

Yo adaptaría (que no traduciría, porque tampoco creo que sea una traducción correcta) pues el correo que mencionas en la pregunta de este modo:

> Sé que somos una panda de *cracks* harto trabajadores, pero...

Comment: The main implication of *go-getter* is ambition; the main implication of *crack* is high skill (as in the definition you cited). A go-getter might *acquire* crack skills, but they're not the same thing.

Comment: "luchador" or "ser una persona luchadora" does not have any of those negative nuances, while conveying the sense of ambition.

Answer (score 4):

A `go-getter` person, could be translated as

> alguien **emprendedor** y **resuelto**
>
> alguien que se consagra con cuanto esfuerzo se necesita para conseguir lo que quiere

also

> una persona **determinada**, **solvente** y **capaz**;  alquien que encara los desafios y no se arredra por las dificultades hasta conseguir lo que se propone , (informalmente lo que también se designa como "un ganador**")

The cited paragraph

> *I know that we are a group of go-getters and a group of very smart and hardworking people but [it's important to have a good work-life balance: here are some tips].*

could get understood in Spanish as

> *Se que somos un grupo de gente determinada y trabajadora [*industriosa*] *pero es importante alcanzar un necesario balance entre  vida personal y laboral, para lo cual van los siguientes consejos.*

Note here the option of the word [industrioso](https://dle.rae.es/industrioso?m=form) (que se dedica con ahínco al trabajo / one that works with special dedication)

Comment: go-getter='una fiera' (en el diccionario argentino/maradoniano)

Answer (score 2):

The RAE dictionary contains

**buscavidas**

2. m. y f. coloq. Persona diligente en buscarse por cualquier medio lícito el modo de vivir.

However, I've never heard it used in daily language.

Comment: I have heard it being used in normal language, and it has a certain tone to it, for as far as i'm aware this is mostly used on people in the lower spectrum of income, and is usually used to define the kind of people that will take any job, no matter how shitty it is to survive and/or provide for their family. I've also heard it in a bit more of a negative tone, as in people who will not shy away from shady business as long as it gets them the money they need. Of course this all depends on context.

Comment: +1 for the contribution. It's interesting. As other explain in the comments it has certain connotations. You wouldn't (shouldn't!) put in your resume that you are a "buscavidas". I don't know if other connotations have slightly different meaning, but the common understanding is that not all the things a "buscavidas" would do would be licit.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el término que mejor toma las características que describes (tras una búsqueda) puede ser [*Osado*](https://dle.rae.es/osado?m=form). Siendo osado alguien que tiene osadía, valga decir que osadía es:

> Atrevimiento, resolución.

Si bien es sinónimo de *decidido*, propuesto por Charlie, suena distinto decir que 'es un empleado es decidido' a 'es un empleado osado'. O en la letra de Gustavson (...)ella es **osada** (...) me parece que suena bien.

Comment: "osado", just like "audaz", has a negative connotation, which "go-getter" does not have.